# How to fix gksu / kdesudo? kdesudo(2831) KDESu::KDESuPrivate::KCookie::getXCookie: No X authentication info set for display ":0"

Tags: sudo, gksu

Command (in terminal):
    leafpad

Result: Leafpad without root rights working fine.

What did I do to cause the error? Maybe I accidentally run

```
sudo leafpad
```

Now I am having problems... Neither kdesudo nor gksu are functional.

Command:

```
kdesudo leafpad
```

Error:

```
kdesudo(2831) KDESu::KDESuPrivate::KCookie::getXCookie: No X authentication info set for display  ":0" 

No protocol specified
No protocol specified
leafpad: Cannot open display:
```

Command:

```
gksu leafpad
```

Error:

```
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

What must I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in the Konsole/Terminal:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority
```

That should fix the problem, as new `.Xauthority` files will be created as needed.

In the future, when running graphical apps as `root`, you can avoid creating this and other problems by using a [graphical frontend](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) like `kdesudo` (or `gksu`/`gksudo`) rather than invoking `sudo` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The error I had was I think very similar:

```
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

I installed [gnome-keyring [image: Install gnome-keyring]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-keyring) and its dependencies and my problem was solved. My best guess is that the run of `apt-get autoremove` has caused this error in the first place. (I do not recommend to run this command).