# kdesudo does not work in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, sudo, system-settings

I recently installed Kubuntu 14.04, after which `kdesudo` seems to work only half the time. For example:

```
$ kdesudo systemsettings
kdesudo(29361) KDESu::KDESuPrivate::KCookie::getXCookie: No X authentication info set for display  ":0.0" 

QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
systemsettings(29368): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
" 

systemsettings(29367): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
```

This never happened in my previous versions (12.04 and 13.10), and is quite annoying... I don't know of any other way to run systemsettings with root privileges! I know this bug was reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166896/how-to-fix-gksu-kdesudo-kdesudo2831-kdesukdesuprivatekcookiegetxcooki), but no one seems to have come up with a solution to that one :-( I tried removing `.Xauthority`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any advice would be really, really welcome :-)

Comment: Related but not a duplicate This question [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](http://askubuntu.com/q/284306/107450) may provide a work round for you.

Answer (score 0):

Overall just running it with sudo then the application name works just as well and displays a log in the terminal you ran it from. Not the same but it works.